# UK Lyca mobile for roaming in Europe

Tags: europe, cellphones, roaming

I will be travelling to London then France and then to Germany and will be buying Lycamobile SIM for calling to India + data browsing.
After going through all the details on net, it seems i should be buying separate sim cards of Lycamobile in each country as it will be cheaper.

Anyone knows of a better option because with above plan, i will be changing my mobile number in each country. best option would be a single sim for all the countries.

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/EE_Limited You can use EE. It has roaming for all Europe

Comment: If you wait for 3 more months roaming will be cancelled for all sim cards

Comment: @JonathanReez the effect it will have on prepaid sim cards is still unclear

Comment: My trip is next month, so cannot wait for 3 months but when you say roaming will be cancelled then will it apply to data as well i.e. data can be used in any country? That is main issue with Lyca, data is only for UK usage.

Comment: Why not use Skype + get a new simcard (of any operator) in each country?

Answer (score 3):

On [June 15th](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/European_Union_roaming_regulations) all roaming regulations will be abolished within the EU, so you will no longer need to purchase separate SIM cards when traveling. This therefore makes this question moot.

Answer (score 1):

It is impossible to answer such question particularly, but it is possible to give generic guidelines.

First you must determine your consumption requirements. In my case it's mostly internet data, about 100 MB a day, but everyone has individual requirements. Than you check the available bundles/packages on operators, for both internal and roaming. Usually, by higher consumption, buying local SIM card make more sense, because roaming tariffs are very expensive, and no, removing roaming fees will likely change nothing, because the basic price will be based on the 'local' prices, still very expensive compared to bundles/packages.

But by moderate consumption and/or visiting countries where prices are extreme, roaming bundles might be cheaper than local cards. For example, in german ALDI you get (currently) 500 MB mobile internet in EU and Schweiz for 5 Euro for 1 week, and the cheapest SIM card in Schweiz costs 20 CHF, and usually for 15 CHF you get 1 GB data.

Because local cards you can buy only in particular country, you will always need SIM card for country where you start, so you should start your analysis with UK.  By ALDI, you can get 1,5 GB internal internet for 10 Euro, so you can cover it with starter pack (13 Euro). So if you need as much, and the roaming package from UK would cost you more than 13 Euro, buying German SIM would be cheaper.

If the differences are a few Euro, you can spare yourself the problem of buying SIMs. It's another factor to consider.